# laravel slow query issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to optimize my query I am executing with Laravel. I'm using MySQL for my project and I have a table named `locations`. It has more than 2 million records.
When I execute the code below it's too slow. How can I optimize my query to improve the speed?

```
foreach ($employees as $employee){
    $percentage = 0;
    if ($employee->position->zones->count() > 0) {
        if($employee->position->zones->first()->workingzones->count() > 0) {
            $workingZone = $employee->position->zones->first()->workingzones->last();
            $tagCode = $employee->rfids->first()->rfid_id;
            $zoneTime = DB::table('location')
                ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                ->where('tagCode', $tagCode)
                ->where('xLocation', '>', $workingZone->x1)
                ->where('xLocation', '<', $workingZone->x3)
                ->where('yLocation', '>', $workingZone->y3)
                ->where('yLocation', '<', $workingZone->y1)
                ->where('locationDate', '>=',''.$currentDate.' 00:00:01')
                ->where('locationDate', '<=', $currentDate. ' 23:59:59')
                ->get();


            $totalWorkedTime = DB::table('location')
                ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                ->where('tagCode', $tagCode)
                ->where('locationDate', '>=',''.$currentDate.' 00:00:01')
                ->where('locationDate', '<=', $currentDate. ' 23:59:59')->get();


                if ($zoneTime->first()->count == 0 || $totalWorkedTime->first()->count == 0) {
                    $percentage = 0;
                }else {
                    $percentage = (int)ceil(($zoneTime->first()->count /12 )* 100 / ($totalWorkedTime->first()->count  / 12));
                }
            }
        }

        $employee->percentage = $percentage;
    }
```

Comment: use chunk for getting results

Comment: still same nothing changed

Answer (score 2):

You do a full `->get()` twice and only use the `->first()` result. When you just need 1, just use `->first()` instead of `->get()`.

---

Also you can eagerload the position and zones while fetching the employees , and saving 2 additional queries per loop (- grouped eagerload queries on total), like this:

```
$employees = Employee::where(/*where foo here*/)
    ->with('position.zones')
    ->get();
```

---

And to consume less mem, chunk it.

```
Employee::where(/*where foo here*/)
    ->with('position.zones')
    ->chunk(200, function ($employees) {
        foreach ($employees as $employee) {
            // current code here with ->first() instead of ->get()
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thats speed up my queries but its still slow to get objects.

Comment: Then the correct question is: why do you want to process 2M records in a request? Assuming that you do that since you say it's too slow. Processing a percentage is something you can do in a job, you don't want to do stuff like this in a request...

Comment: cause I need the get count of objects in this records. So When I try it with foreach after your answer its faster then first version but still its slow I just try to get counts faster.

Answer (score 0):

Adding indexes on the following columns should improve your performance:

- `xLocation`
- `yLocation`
- `locationDate`

How to add indexes with an MySQL query:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

or if you use Laravel's migrations: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#indexes

**Edit:**

Also: instead of doing the `COUNT(*)` on both select queries, use `` COUNT(`id`) ``, so you don't count all columns, but only the `id` column

Comment: @MuratKaya Can you tell me what data types the `xLocation` and `yLocation` are?

Comment: @MuratKaya also tell us more about `locationDate`. It's probably a mysql datetime. A substring search could speed it up. `where('substr(locationDate,0,10)', '<>', $currentDate)`

Comment: It should be `where('substr(locationDate,0,10)', '=', $currentDate)` or even `where('substr(locationDate,0,10)', $currentDate)`

Comment: @DimitriMostrey  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'substr(locationDate,0,10)' in 'where clause'

Comment: my bad, hadn't test it. This should work: `whereRaw("substr(locationDate,1,10) = '$currentDate'")`